# How to get a user type using python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am using python-telegram-bot for my bot. I would like to know if a user is a normal user, channel, bot, or group.

Example:

```
user_type = x_func("@practice_english")
print(user_type) # User type should be channel here.
```

What is the x_func that can do this task for me?

Comment: You could use the `Bot.get_chat("@practice_english")` method which will return a [chat-object](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.chat.html). This object has a `.type` attribute that can "be either ‘private’, ‘group’, ‘supergroup’ or ‘channel’." If it is 'private'. You can further check if it is a bot or a user by `Bot.get_chat_member("@practice_english")`. But you will need some custom logic. Read the docs [here](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.html).

Comment: note that `get_chat` accepts usernames only for supergroups and channels. For normal groups & private chats, you'll have to pass the chat id. Then again, if you already have the chat_id, you can already tell: positive chat_id -> user, negative -> group, negative with a leading -100 -> supergroup or channel

Comment: Thank you, guys! Now I can get the info if the mention is a channel or supergroup. However, I am getting the following error for normal user and bot: `caused error Chat not found`
For get_chat_member, it cannot work for me because I don't have the chat id. The only thing I have is the user_id (@etc)